# Global variables not changing through function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value and name of an input box a person is currently using on keyup, however I'm having trouble with global variables being updated once the keyup function has run. They just continue to say undefined in Google Chrome developer tools.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
                var assessName;
                var assessVal;
                var impName;
                var impVal;

                //Get the name and value of the currently selected assessed input
                $('[id^=ass]').on('keyup', function(){
                    assessName = $(this).attr('name').replace('ass-','');
                    assessVal = $(this).val();
                });

                //Get the name and value of the currently selected implemented input
                $('[id^=imp]').on('keyup', function(){
                    impName = $(this).attr('name').replace('imp-','');
                    impVal = $(this).val();             
                });

                console.log(assessName);
                console.log(assessVal);
                console.log(impName);
                console.log(impVal);
            });
```

Comment: `$('[id^=imp]').on('keyup', ...)` just registers an event listener. It doesn't block the execution of the script and wait until the event is triggered. Put those `console.log()`s into the callback functions and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `keyup` events change `variables` *after* you write them to console. Events in JavaScript are **asynchronous**.

So if you will put your `console.log` call into event listener it will show exactly what you expect.

Comment: Ahh! My understanding of how it worked was incorrect, but I know now! Learned something new today. Thank you!

Comment: @PastorBones There is a 10 minute wait before I can do that. Do not worry, I will do so once the timer runs out...